# Best practices for updating a live website

Tags: php, mysql, database, version-control

**Situation:**

1. I've just deployed the first version of my website (in PHP with MySQL database). I now need to move to version 2 of my website.
2. I typically build my website on localhost before moving it to the production server
3. I now want to restructure my database. But I'm not clear how to do this without losing / corrupting existing user data.
4. I'm worried that WHILE I'm making the above changes, a user may try to make edits to the database.

**Questions for you**

1. I need to test my code on my server, but I don't want to expose it to the public while I'm doing so. What's the best practice to handle this? Are there multiple options here?
2. Let's say I restructure my database in localhost. How do I duplicate this restructuring on the live server? Do I need to run every query on both localhost and production servers? (Seems very inefficient - is there a better way to do this?)
3. How do I make sure that while I'm restructuring the database, the
   sanctity of the data is not harmed (i.e. how do I make sure the
   "version" of the database does not change until I finish my job?)
4. Let's say I screw up and I need to "undo" the changes to my code. What's the best way to revert to the original version of the website? Do I need to retrieve a backed up version and lose any interim changes?
5. Is there a general list of Do's & Don'ts regarding process flow? Would appreciate any helpful links.

Comment: Don't have display errors on in production. Log them. Don't test on your live domain, make a subdomain on live main server and test there, this should give you the same environment tests.

Comment: This question is really broad and opinion-based, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow. In the future, ask specific, objective questions. Also, no need to explain why you're posting, or adding thanks; that's just superfluous.

Comment: @DavidMakogon.. I don't quite see the rationale of closing this question. I was getting quite helpful answers (none of which were contradicting or very different). Questions are already quite specific and the two answers I got are bang on target. Honestly, this feels like moderation for the sake of moderation..

Comment: @Sam - it's closed because it's broad and opinion-based. Yes, you got two answers. One with a library recommendation, one with a workflow. And likely would get two (or a dozen or a hundred) more. Not one of them will be an objective "this is *the* way it is done" answer. This is just how StackOverflow is. It's not a discussion forum. And this isn't moderation for the sake of moderation.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sure.. Whatever makes you feel more relevant Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can clone your production site on the same server with a different domain. For example staging.yourdomain.com and protect it with a password
2. You can write a migration sql file that contains all the changes (ALTER TABLE...). You can then execute this migration file during the deployment process
3. You should use a deployment tool like capistrano to automate the deployment process.
4. When you use a deployment tool, you can do the following:

   - Create a directory struture that allows you to symlink the versions
     /www-data -> symlink to /releases/version2
     /releases/version1
     /releases/version2
   - Deploy the php files in a new directory under /releases
   - Backup your production DB
   - Do any other tasks you need for deployment (like js minifying)
   - In the end, when every task run properly, change the symlink to /www-data to /release/version3

Answer (score 0):

For PHP there is [Phinx](https://phinx.org/), a library to write migrations on your database.

As for software, databases can have versions. Phinx allow you to write migrations programmatically via an API. Each time you'll add a "migration" it will create a file that describe all the changes. Then you'll have to apply the migrations with the Command Line Interface (CLI).

It's ALWAYS necessary to keep backups of your database (tables and data), at least one very day. If something bad happen when you manually (or not) alter the database you'll have a backup to restore.